# How to pass a variable to deserializeUser when using PassportJs?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using PassportJS in my SailsJs app.

I have a few urls (widgets), which just require to check if user is authenticated, they do not need complete user details. The user id is being saved in session and would suffice.

```
module.exports.policies = {
    *   : [passport.initialize(),passport.session()],
    WidgetController : [passport.initialize(),passport.session(/*just userid flag */)]
}
```

my passport.js file has the following in deserialize user.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (userSession, done) {
    if(/** just user id flag **/)
        done(null,userSession.id)
    else{
        User.findById(userSession.id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        }
    }
}
```

How do i pass a flag so that widget controller does not require to run a query requiring user details?

Comment: It's a callback so you kind of can't. Maybe you could pass the data through the session object?

Comment: Session is permanent right, Like these widgets are loaded by ajax calls  in a page. The main page requires deserialize, widgets do not need it.

Comment: Nope, I used a work around by checking the last login time and fetching the user details only once in 5 mins